# Reversing/Debugging - Finding out when an exception handler was installed

Tags: c, windows, debugging, exception, reverse-engineering

While reversing a program (needless to say: for educational purpose only), my debugger (OllyDbg) cought a program's exception (access violation).

I threw the exception back to the program and the program continued execution, starting from a certain address.

What I'm trying to find out is when this exception handler was installed (AKA where are the __try{}__except{} blocks in the assembly) but I can not find any cross-references to the address that the program continued execution from.

I managed to find that address while runtime debugging by finding the correct EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION structure on the stack but I want is to find a method to identify the address statically and not only at runtime.

Help will be very appreciated.

**--EDIT--:**
Let me clarify, what I am trying to find is the

```
__try
{
    do_error();
}
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
    do_stuff();
    return...;
}
```

block in assembly

Comment: Access violations typically result from an invalid operation on a pointer.   They are not generally associated with `try` or `catch` blocks, or similar constructs.   When an error is detected, the cause is in previously executed code - there is no way to get to the cause by throwing the error "back to the program" and continuing execution.

Comment: @Peter: he's looking for the reason that the exception was *caught*, not the reason the exception was *thrown*.

Comment: @Harry - the question is also tagged "debugging".   If that's the purpose, then my comment is relevant.  Either way, the machinery of catching exceptions is not required to be part of the executable, so there's nothing there to be reverse engineered - it would be necessary to reverse engineer windows (or its libraries), not the program.

Comment: @Peter: the question asks how to find the code that installed the exception handler.  That code is definitely part of the application, not part of Windows.  (If an application *doesn't* install an exception handler, the default exception handler is invoked, which didn't happen in this case.)  [I think the "debugging" tag is just because he's using a debugger, not because he's trying to debug the third-party program.  CodeNinja, could you please clarify?]

Comment: (Granted, it is unusual for an application to catch access violations, or to intentionally generate them.  But not entirely unknown.)

Comment: Hello, let me clarify. The program intentionally access memory with no privileges, then catches the exception and continue execution from another point in the code. What I am trying to find out is where the address to continue execution from is referenced in the exception handling mechanism. (for example, I am trying to find the following code in the assembly: __try{do_error();}__except{continue_from_address();})

Comment: @HarryJohnston is this answering your question?

Comment: @CodeNinja: First of all, please edit your question and change all instances of "installing an exception" to "installing an exception *handler*" because it is very confusing otherwise. Secondly, exception handlers are installed by pointing the memory at `fs:[0]` to a EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION which is another layer of abstraction around the exception handler definition (often located on the stack). So you would need to find the place where something like `mov fs:[0], esp` or `xor eax, eax; mov fs:[eax], esp` is used. [Details here](http://www.stoned-vienna.com/windows-exception-handling.html)

Comment: @CherryDT, thank you. the EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION is the structure I found on the stack which indicated the handler routine address that I wanted to find. I have read a similar article **"A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling"**. I will try looking at all the locations that access the fs register.